# Difference in file system type on mount and Disk Utility

Tags: filesystems, mount, ntfs, fuse, fat

Here the `type` is `fuseblk`:

```
$ mount
/dev/sdb1 on /media/me/MY-DEVICE type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Can see below that the `Partition Type` is `HPFS/NTFS` and conents is `exFAT`.

[image]

Why the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mount on `/media` is a [FUSE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) mount - a userspace filesystem mount. The underlying filesystem being mounted by the FUSE driver could be anything, including filesystems that may not be supported by the kernel. The Gnome desktop makes use of it for mounting USB keys and other removable media.

FUSE allows safe mounting of filesystems without granting root access to users. You could alternatively mount a FAT fs (but not exFAT, which is not supported by a kernel module in the way the various older FAT filesystems are) with e.g.

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /mnt/myfs
```

Comment: Fair enough, answer updated accordingly.